# Syntax error Jython

Tags: python, jython

I am getting a syntax error in my code. Can anyone say what's wrong in the syntax? I am new to this language, don't have much of an idea.

Error message

> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "JDBCoracle.py"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython: Traceback (innermost last): (no code object) at line 0 File "", line 8 name ="Oracle JDBC Driver" ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My code :

```
import sys

   ## **JDBCProvider** ##

   def OracleJDBC(cellName,serverName,):


   name ="Oracle JDBC Driver"

   print " Name of JDBC Provider which will be created ---> " + name

   print "
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

   # Gets the name of cell

   cell = AdminControl.getCell() print cell

   cellid = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:'+ cell +'/')

   print cellid print "
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

   ## Creating New JDBC Provider ##

   print " Creating New JDBC Provider :"+ name 

   n1 = ["name" , "Oracle JDBC Driver" ]

   desc = ["description" , "Oracle JDBC Driver"]

   impn = ["implementationClassName" ,
   "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"]

   classpath = ["classpath" , ${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar ]

   attrs1 = [n1 , impn , desc , classpath]

   Serverid = AdminConfig.getid("/Cell:"+ cellName +"/ServerName:"+
   serverName +"/")

   jdbc = AdminConfig.create('JDBCProvider' , Serverid , attrs1)

   print " New JDBC Provider created :"+ name 

   AdminConfig.save()

   print " Saving Configuraion " 

   print "
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

   ####################################################################################################################
   ####################################################################################################################

   #main program starts here

   OracleJDBC(cellName,serverName)
```

Can some one help me see what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to this language.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is the comma in `def OracleJDBC(cellName,serverName,):`; eliminate it and things will work.

```
import sys

## **JDBCProvider** ##

def OracleJDBC(cellName,serverName):
    name ="Oracle JDBC Driver"
    print " Name of JDBC Provider which will be created ---> " + name
    print "   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    # Gets the name of cell
    cell = AdminControl.getCell() print cell
    cellid = AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:'+ cell +'/')
    print cellid
    print "   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    ## Creating New JDBC Provider ##
    print " Creating New JDBC Provider :"+ name 
    n1 = ["name" , "Oracle JDBC Driver" ]
    desc = ["description" , "Oracle JDBC Driver"]
    impn = ["implementationClassName" ,
            "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"]
    classpath = ["classpath" , '/path/to/ojdbc6.jar' ]
    attrs1 = [n1 , impn , desc , classpath]

    n1 = ["name" , "Oracle JDBC Driver" ]

    desc = ["description" , "Oracle JDBC Driver"]

    impn = ["implementationClassName" , "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"]

    classpath = ["classpath" , ${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar ]

    attrs1 = [n1 , impn , desc , classpath]

    Serverid = AdminConfig.getid("/Cell:" + cellName + "/ServerName:" + serverName +"/")

    jdbc = AdminConfig.create('JDBCProvider', Serverid, attrs1)

    print " New JDBC Provider created :" + name 

    AdminConfig.save()

    print " Saving Configuraion " 

    print "   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "

    ####################################################################################################################
    ####################################################################################################################

#main program starts here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    OracleJDBC(cellName,serverName)
```

Comment: That's an additional error, that wasn't reported by OP :)

Comment: i have removed comma in  even after that i am getting same error

Comment: Whatr is indentation ?

Comment: can you please tell me what do you mean by indentation ?

Comment: I've fixed your problems and posted correctly indented code, @AAMIRAZAM

Comment: Hi , yes that problem got fixed , but after that i am also getting one error

Comment: WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "jdbcConn.jy"; exception information: com.ibm.bsf.BSFException: exception from Jython: Traceback (innermost last): (no code object) at line 0 File "", line 29 classpath = ["classpath" , ${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar ] ^ SyntaxError: Lexical error at line 29, column 32. Encountered: "$" (36), after : ""

Comment: @AAMIRAZAM it's strongly encouraged that you attempt to learn Python. `${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar` is not a valid value.

Comment: @AAMIRAZAM try now?